# Angular 4 - service data is not persistent

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html5-audio, angular-services

I am having some trouble figuring out where I went wrong and would really appreciate some help with this.

I have a component: `AudioComponent`, which captures an html5  tag as a `@ViewChild`, then registers itself with a service: `AudioService`.

Here is the `AudioComponent`:

```
/* audio.component.ts */
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IAudioOptions } from './audio-options';

export const defaultOptions: IAudioOptions = {
  controls: true,
  autoplay: false,
  loop: false,
  volume: 1.0,
  startPosition: 0.0,
  preload: "metadata",
  muted: false
};

@Component({
  selector: 'ng-audio',
  templateUrl: './audio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./audio.component.css']
})
export class AudioComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() src: any;
  @Input() options: any = defaultOptions;
  @Input() register: any;

  @ViewChild('audio') player: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.register) {
      console.log("registering");
      console.log(this.register(this));
    }
  }

  play() {
    this.player.nativeElement.play();
  }

}
```

And the `AudioService`:

```
/* audio.service.ts */
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AudioComponent } from './audio/audio.component';

@Injectable()
export class AudioService {
  private players: AudioComponent[];

  constructor() { }

  register(player: AudioComponent) {
    console.log("player registered");
    if (this.players) {
      this.players.push(player);
    }
    else {
      console.log("initializing service");
      this.players = [];
      this.players.push(player);
    }
    return this.players;
  }

  getPlayers(): string[] {
    var out: string[];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.players.length; i++) {
      out.push(this.players[i].src);
    }
    return out;
  }

}
```

I'm instantiating two of the `ng-audio` components in my `app.component.html` file:

```
<!-- register refers to the AudioService.register function -->
<ng-audio [src]="src" [register]="register"></ng-audio>
<ng-audio [src]="src2" [register]="register"></ng-audio>
```

And the audio players themselves appear when I load the page.

What's puzzling is that I get the following logged to the console:

```
- registering
- player registered
- initializing service
- [AudioComponent]
- registering
- player registered
- initializing service // <- this should only happen the first time!
- [AudioComponent]     // <- and this should now contain two elements!
```

For some reason, the `players: AudioComponent[]` property of the `AudioService` does not persist. So each time `register()` is called, it's like I'm calling it on a completely new `AudioService` instance!

Again, any help will be greatly appreciated. I'll be posting updates if I can figure this out.

EDIT: I've included my `app.module.ts` and `app.component.ts` files in case there's something I missed setting up the service as a provider.

`AppModule`:

```
/* app.module.ts */
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AudioComponent } from './audio/audio.component';
import { AudioService } from './audio.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AudioComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  exports: [AudioComponent],
  providers: [AudioService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And `AppComponent`:

```
/* app.component.ts */
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AudioComponent } from './audio/audio.component';

import { AudioService } from './audio.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  src = 'http://url.to/file.mp3';
  src2 = 'http://url.to/another-file.mp3';
  interval: any;
  player: AudioComponent;

  register: any;
  play: any;

  constructor(
    private service: AudioService
  ) {
    this.register = this.service.register;
    this.play = this.service.getPlayers;
  }
}
```

Comment: I find "some strange" you use "register" as input. You always can write this.service.register(); But I don't know if you remove the tags [register] solve your problem

Comment: try to add `console.log` in the service constructor to see if angular initialises two instances or not.

Comment: @MartinNuc I added "console.log('constructing service')" to the AudioService's constructor, and 'constructing service' only appeared once in the console with four instances of the audio component being instantiated.

Comment: @Eliseo - using register() worked! Thank you! I'll post a thorough answer once I figure out a couple more bugs.

Comment: @Spencer can you kindly post your answer?